# Why does WebClien

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I can try to get string from url but when i do my program GUI freezes

Comment: What version of .NET are you targetting?

Comment: It freezes because WebClient is synchronous so it will block the entirety of the loop.

Comment: i using .Net 3.5 , so – Fran what i must do ?

Comment: wait for the request to complete? Or find out why it takes so long. You're right though, `await` isn't available until .NET 4.5

Comment: Program work is nice after check all urls and do what im say that but in this time all ui is frezz and example i see after 30 sec do work and program re usableable

Comment: i no use any function and other class after from1 . do all things in button

Comment: no when a click on button start testing and program freez to end checking

Comment: The easiest way is to put code into Background Work which will run async.

Comment: sorry for bad english

Comment: i try to use async but not secsessed , so how i can use it in button and my program not frezz

Comment: Also, the presence of `MyIrancell BruteForce  [ Status : Attacking ]` in your question makes it somewhat questionable!

Answer (score 3):

If you're targetting .NET before 4.5 there is no async/await  - instead you can use the async version of `DownloadStringAsync` which raises an event when the string is downloaded

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCompletedHandler);

for (long i = 1; i < gethow; i++)
{
    string WebAdress = "https://xxxxxx.xxx/web?id=";
    var request = WebAdress + (fromNumber - 1 + i);    

    client.DownloadStringAsync(request);

}

// -- > Elsewhere in your form
void DownloadStringCompletedHandler(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    slas = "0" + Convert.ToString((fromNumber - 1 + i));
    if (e.Result == "Test")
    {
        if (!listBox1.Items.Contains(slas))
        {                
             listBox1.Items.Add(slas);
             godn++;
         }
    }
}
```

If all of your code *must* be in your button click, you can inline the event handler

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s,e) => {
    slas = "0" + Convert.ToString((fromNumber - 1 + i));
    if (e.Result == "Test")
    {
        if (!listBox1.Items.Contains(slas))
        {                
             listBox1.Items.Add(slas);
             godn++;
         }
    }
};

for (long i = 1; i < gethow; i++)
{
    string WebAdress = "https://xxxxxx.xxx/web?id=";
    var request = WebAdress + (fromNumber - 1 + i);    

    client.DownloadStringAsync(request);

}
```

---

Edit: You have updated your code in the question to be like this answer but youve assumed `DownloadStringAsync` returns the result - it doesn't. That method returns nothing. The string is returned in the event handler

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCompletedHandler);
result=client.DownloadStringAsync(request); // <-- This line is wrong
```

It should be

```
client.DownloadStringAsync(request);
```

And receive the string inside `DownloadStringCompletedHandler` as `e.Result`

Comment: good but i dont like to use class ( all works must me inside button )

Comment: @Pwn3rGamer im afraid that comment makes no sense. What do you mean? By class I mean your form!

Comment: where is result ? result inside result must be downloaded string from url

Comment: _all works must me inside button_ i smell (heavy) logic in UI code... @Pwn3rGamer you should take the code into a other class and just call it when the button is clicked... writing the logic directly inside the eventhandler for the buttonclick is not good

Comment: @Pwn3rGamer the result is in the event handler - `e.Result` (sorry, I had missed that on first writing)

Comment: @Jamiec please see my full code i will edit my question

Comment: @Jamiec my english is not good so a can Little understand what you say to help . i share full code please fix problem thanks

Comment: please i dont understand please

Comment: @Pwn3rGamer I have updated my answer again, but thats as much as I can do.

Comment: @Jamiec  pleeeeeeeeeeeeeaseeeee say it simpley im not understand help

Comment: @Jamiec  client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s,e) => { what is s and e ?

Comment: `s` is the sender of the event (probably the webclient instance). `e` is the event args containing the response info (and in this case result of the download)